# Writing $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ as the zero-set of a function

Tags: functions, manifolds, lie-groups

Here I'm assuming $M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{4}$. The definition of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ is:

$\mathrm{SO}(2)=\{ \ A \in M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \ | \ \det(A)=1 \mathrm{\ and\ }AA^{T}=I\ \}$

With some work I have shown that this is equivalent to:

$\mathrm{SO}(2)=\left\{ \ A \in M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \ \bigg| \ A=\left[ \begin{matrix} \ a & b\  \\ -b & a\ \end{matrix} \right]\mathrm{\ such\ that\ }a^2+b^2=1 \ \right\}$

I would like to find a smooth function $F:M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{4} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that:

$\mathrm{SO}(2)=\{\ A \in M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R})\ | \ F(A) = 0\ \}$

I know that such a function must exist, but I can't quite figure it out. My idea was to set:

$F\left( \left[ \begin{matrix} \ a & b\  \\ \ c & d\ \end{matrix} \right] \right) = \left[ \begin{matrix} \ a - d \\ \ b + c\  \end{matrix} \right]$

But I don't think this is correct. The above function forces $d=a$ and $c=-b$ but I don't know how to force the $a^2+b^2=1$ condition. What am I missing?

Comment: $SO(2)$ has dimension $1$, to write it as the zero set of a smooth function, it is therefore better to take $\mathbb{R}^3$ as the codomain.

Comment: Oops huge mistake on my part! Now I see what to do; with $F:M_{2 \times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ I define:$F\left( \left[ \begin{matrix} \ a & b\  \\ \ c & d\ \end{matrix} \right] \right) = \left[ \begin{matrix} \ a - d \\ \ b + c\ \\ a^2 + b^2 - 1  \end{matrix} \right]$

Comment: @DanielFischer: why? $f(x, y, z) = x^2+y^2+z^2$ defines a smooth function from $\Bbb{R}^3$ to $\Bbb{R}$ such that $f(\mathbf{v}) = 0$ iff $\mathbf{v} = 0$. So if you can solve the problem with codomain $\Bbb{R}^3$, you can also solve it with codomain $\Bbb{R}$. The dimension of $SO(2)$ is not relevant.

Comment: @RobArthan Sure, you can write it as the zero set of a continuous (even smooth) real-valued function, since it's closed. It's just easier to separate the conditions, so that each component reduces the dimension by one, and if you do it right, you get the fact that it is a submanifold of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ automatically, which you wouldn't if you took a codomain of smaller dimension than $\dim M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) - \dim SO(2)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: well your comment seems to have pleased the OP even though it doesn't lead without further work to an answer to the question as stated (with $\Bbb{R}^2$ as the codomain), so who am I to complain?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was trying to find a function $F:M_{2 \times 2} \to \mathbb{R}^{4-k}$, where $k$ is the dimension of $\mathrm{SO}(2)$. I mistakenly thought that $k=2$, but it's $k=1$. I am trying to find such a function in order to prove that $\mathrm{SO}(2)$ is a smooth manifold.